# What prevents abuse of Firebase's createUserWithEmailAndPassword?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase has a function 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' that can be called from the frontend to create a user.

What prevents someone from manually invoking the function from inside your javascript code multiple times? Won't it just keep creating users with no way to authenticate legitimacy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a risk however there are some limits that can be put in place. On the firebase console > Authentication > Sign-in method tab > scroll to the bottom you will see this message

> Manage sign-up quota
>
> To protect your project from abuse, we limit the number of new
>   Email/Password and Anonymous sign-ups that your application can have
>   from the same IP address. You can request and schedule temporary
>   changes to this quota here.
>
> Current quota per hour: 100

You can apply to change this quotas to reduce the amount that can be performed.

You also should look into how else to authorise your users because although they have an account that is just a superficial user account that you need to then work out how to authorise their access.

E.g. for an internal application although anyone can register i use an auth onCreate trigger to detect if the email is from an approved domain and if not i delete and if it is i attach a [custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) which i can use in my security rules and on the front end client to authorise.

It all depends on your application to define which accounts get access to your app.